# Connect 3rd Device using GameKit

Tags: iphone, gamekit, gksession

I am using GameKit on a basic level right now. I am able to connect two devices and send messages between them.

I have 3 devices, we'll call them device A, B and C.

I am able to connect A to B, A to C, and B to C, as individual setups.

If I connect A to B, then attempt to connect B to C, Device C will show that Device B is available, but device B continues to spin and say "Looking for available iPod, iPhones..."

In `peerPickerController:sessionForConnectionType:` , when I am attempting to connect B to C, I am trying to have device B reuse its same `GKSession` that it is using in its connection to A... because if I create a new session on device B, it is able to connect to Device C but drops the connection to device A.

Here is the `sessionForConnectionType` :

```
 -(GKSession*)peerPickerController:(GKPeerPickerController *)picker sessionForConnectionType:(GKPeerPickerConnectionType)type {

   // session is a synthesized GKSession
        if (session == nil) {
            session = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:nil  displayName:@"" sessionMode:GKSessionModePeer];
            session.delegate = self;        
        } 


        return session;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up going with a Server / Client setup, which is easier to manage. This way, there is only one Server PeerID, as opposed to a Server PeerID for every connection. I wasn't able to find many good examples, so I've included the basic GameKit Server / Client code here.

```
// if the device in an ipad, treat it as a host / server
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPad"]) {
        isHost = YES;
    } else {
        isHost = NO;
    }

// monitor if this device is connected to another device
    isConnected = NO;
}




#pragma mark GameKit Methods

// Called when a change in the connection state is detected
- (void)session:(GKSession *)session peer:(NSString *)peerID didChangeState:(GKPeerConnectionState)state {

    NSLog(@"Session:Peer:%@ Did Change State", peerID);
     Globals *globals = [Globals shareData];

    switch (state) {
        case GKPeerStateConnected:
            NSLog(@"GKPeerStateConnected");

            [globals.localSession setDataReceiveHandler:self withContext:nil];

// if this device is not the host and is not connected yet...
            if (!isHost && !isConnected) {

// update variables, save the Server PeerId and the local Session so we can use them later 
                isConnected = YES;
                serverSession = peerID];
                localSession = session;
            }
            break;

        case GKPeerStateDisconnected:
            NSLog(@"GKPeerStateDisconnected");
            break;

        case GKPeerStateAvailable:
            NSLog(@"GKPeerStateAvailable");
            if (!isHost) {
                NSLog(@"Attempting to Connect...");
// the server is available, try to connect to it
                [session connectToPeer:peerID withTimeout:20];
            }
            break;

        case GKPeerStateConnecting:
            NSLog(@"GKPeerStateConnecting");
            break;

        case GKPeerStateUnavailable:
            NSLog(@"GKPeerStateUnavailable");
            break;
    }

}

// Called if this device receives a request for a connection
// This should only happen on the Server device
-(void)session:(GKSession *)session didReceiveConnectionRequestFromPeer:(NSString *)peerID {
    NSLog(@"Received Connection Request From %@", peerID);

// Accept the connection request from the peer
    [session acceptConnectionFromPeer:peerID error:nil];
}

- (void)receiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(NSString *)peer inSession:(GKSession *)session context:(void *)context {
    NSLog(@"Received Data");   
}

-(void)session:(GKSession *)session didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Session Failed: %@", error);
}


// Connected to a UIButton
-(IBAction)sendData {
    NSLog(@"Sending Data ...");   
}

// Connected to a UIButton
-(IBAction)beginConnection {

    Globals *globals = [Globals shareData];

// Set this up as a server
    if (isHost) {
        GKSession *session = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:@"" displayName:@"Server" sessionMode:GKSessionModeServer];
        session.delegate = self;
        session.available = YES;       
        NSLog(@"Setting Server Session Peer:%@",  session.peerID);
        globals.localSession = session;
    } 

// or set it up as a client
else {
        GKSession *session = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:@"" displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModeClient];
        session.delegate = self;
        session.available = YES;
        NSLog(@"Setting CLIENT Session Peer:%@", session.peerID);
        globals.localSession = session;
    }

}


... Dealloc, etc...

@end
```

Comment: Hey Chris, I am looking to implement Client Server Model for iOS devices. I am not finding much of information on that can you suggest me some pointer or resources that I can use ?

Comment: @SumitLonkar Here's a post I wrote regarding this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/12738287/1079207)