# Transfer data over wifi without a database

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, data-transfer

I want to get to know how I can transfer data easily between 2 iPhones, over wifi. I would like to know if I could do that without having a server or database, but within an app (so without using email).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transfer files between 2 iPhones over wifi?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637598/transfer-files-between-2-iphones-over-wifi)

Comment: See also [Any API to share data between two iphones/ipod touches/ipads? (Except GameKit)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584348/any-api-to-share-data-between-two-iphones-ipod-touches-ipads-except-gamekit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Game Kit has support for [Peer-to-Peer-Connectivity](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH100-SW1) and is, despite the name, not only usable for games:

> The GKSession class allows your application to create and manage an
>   ad-hoc Bluetooth or local wireless network, as shown in Figure 1.
>   Copies of your application running on multiple devices can discover
>   each other and exchange information, providing a simple and powerful
>   way to create multiplayer games on iOS. Further, sessions offer all
>   applications an exciting mechanism to allow users to collaborate with
>   each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check out Bonjour API from Apple. I am not sure if you need a static IP for it to work or it can just work over wifi. Just trying to give a pointer.

Based on your exact usecase, it can work well.

Check it out here, Game center is also there.
http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/networking.html